# Hacer Pagina Siguiente anterior con mumero tal como en la imagen

Tags: php, sql

me gustaria dividir el **select ItemID** que es un maximo de 25000 registros asi como esta imagen pero que tome solo **SELECT top 255 ItemID FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items** para no sobre cargar la web.

quisiera hacer este boton e integrarlo en el scrip php para comenzar no se como se llama este proceso de paginacion.

**¿Alguien sabe como hacer lo de la imagen de abajo y integrarlo en php?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
// Database configuration parameters
include "../../includes/db_connect2.php";
//Form Data
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$count  = 1;
$rank   = 0;
$cimg   = 0;
$kdr    = 0;
$char  = '???';
$query  = ('SELECT * FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE ItemName NOT LIKE  "%"+\'' . $char . '\'+"%"  ORDER BY ItemID');
$result = mssql_query($query);
echo "Country (6=AOL/UOF,2=AOL,5=UOF) IF A 1 apears in row signifying a class that is class that wears or uses item. /getitem useing Type space TypeID space Count you want.";
echo "<html><head><STYLE TYPE=\"text/css\">
<!--
td { background:url(image.png) no-repeat; }
td.i0{ background-position: 0 0; width: 28px; height: 16px; } 
td.i1{ background-position: 0 -26px; width: 28px; height: 16px; } 
td.i2{ background-position: 0 -52px; width: 28px; height: 16px; } 
td.i3{ background-position: 0 -78px; width: 29px; height: 16px; } 
td.i4{ background-position: 0 -104px; width: 29px; height: 15px; } 
td.i5{ background-position: 0 -129px; width: 28px; height: 18px; } 
td.i6{ background-position: 0 -157px; width: 30px; height: 17px; } 
td.i7{ background-position: 0 -184px; width: 29px; height: 17px; } 
td.i8{ background-position: 0 -211px; width: 28px; height: 16px; } 
td.i9{ background-position: 0 -237px; width: 28px; height: 18px; } 
td.i10{ background-position: 0 -265px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i11{ background-position: 0 -293px; width: 29px; height: 24px; } 
td.i12{ background-position: 0 -327px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i13{ background-position: 0 -355px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i14{ background-position: 0 -383px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i15{ background-position: 0 -411px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i16{ background-position: 0 -439px; width: 29px; height: 18px; } 
td.i17{ background-position: 0 -467px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
td.i18{ background-position: 0 -501px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
td.i19{ background-position: 0 -535px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
td.i20{ background-position: 0 -569px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
td.i21{ background-position: 0 -603px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
td.i22{ background-position: 0 -637px; width: 24px; height: 24px; } 
</STYLE>
<title>Item List</title></head>";
echo "<body><center>
      <table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=0 border=0 bgcolor=\"black\">
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">ItemName</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Type</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">TypeID</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Requierd Level</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Country</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Fight/War</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Def/Guard</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Ranger/Sin</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Archer/Hunter</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Mage/Pag</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Priest/Orc</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Max O.J.Stats</td>
      <td style=\"color:#FC9700\" bgcolor=\"black\">Count Per Stack</td>";
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"color:white\">";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td><td>" . $row[2] . "</td><td>" . $row[3] . "</td><td>" . $row[4] . "</td><td>" . $row[5] . "</td><td>" . $row[6] . "</td><td> " . $row[7] . "</td><td>" . $row[8] . "</td><td>" . $row[9] . "</td><td>" . $row[10] . "</td><td>" . $row[11] . "</td><td>" . $row[17] . "</td><td>" . $row[48] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $count++;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: Puedes solucionar tu problema usando data tables de bootsrap, aqui puedes encontrar la documentación.
[https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap "Documentación data tables")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera de resolver este tema es usando paginación tambien en la consulta. la forma de hacerlo varía en función del motor de base de datos usado, pero asumiendo que es MySQL tendrías que usar `offset`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Básicamente se base en de los N registros que devuelve la consulta que solo te de a partir del registro número X. Con eso tienes resuelto la paginación. Solo tienes que ir calculando el offset en función del número de registros por página.

Espero que te sirva.